# Problems defining new elastic data source in grafana using dots in time field name

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm trying to define a new data source in Grafana
The data source is an Elastic index (which I'm not responsible of)

When trying to `Save & Test` the new data source I get the following error:

> No date field named Date.Epoch found

This field is the same field that is set in the Kibana Index Pattern as the time filter field, So I'm sure there is no typo or some other confusion..

After a lot of searching online I suspect what causes the problem is that we have a dot `.` in the field name.
Is there any way to escape the dot? or another solution without changing the index?

**Update:** I opened an issue in Grafana's github project https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/27702

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, if it worked for you.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't..

Answer (score 2):

Try using advanced [variable formatting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/templates-and-variables/#variable-syntax) and use raw value if you have escaping problems:

`$variable`
or
`${variable:raw}`

Comment: My problem is *not* within a query or a graph, it's within the data source configuration it has nothing to do with variables